# JavaScript function parameter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a javascript function in my html click and pass three parameters in it

```
<div class="save_button" onclick="savetext('text','text_2000','Plan to share my experiences this week.')">Submit</div>
```

This is working fine for the function

```
function savetext(type,text_id,text_body){ 
    // mycode
}
```

**Note:** The 3rd parameter can be any text

When the 3rd parameter came like

```
<div class="save_button" onclick="savetext('text','text_2001','It's hot today, what I'll do? (better not to go outside!).Let's have an ice cream')">Submit</div>
```

showing the error in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I know it due to additional `(` , `)` and `'` coming on the parameter.
But I couldn't able to remove that 3rd parameter because its dynamic

How it can fixed.??

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting..

Comment: are you sure you mentioned a right example?? you are calling function `savetext` and defining funtion `savecomment`

Comment: @ShowStopper Thanks for showing it.. but its same.. both case issue is generating.. I have edited my question :)

Comment: Your third argument needs some handling of escape character as it contains single quote `'It's hot today, what I'll do? (better not to go outside!).Let's have an ice cream'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using quotes `'` inside quote. That is breaking the string and resulting in error.

Escape the quote by preceding with `\`.

See the highlighted changes in below code.

```
<div class="save_button" onclick="savetext('text','text_2001','It\'s hot today, what I\'ll do? (better not to go outside!).Let\'s have an ice cream')">Submit</div>
<!--                                                             ^^                  ^^                                       ^^ -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Just escape any `'` in your parameter using \ and I believe you will be fine.